# Morphism of sheaves $\mathcal{G}\to\iota_*\mathcal{F}$ induced by $\mathcal{G}\big|_Z\to\mathcal{F}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{G}$ a sheaf on it. Let $Z$ be a subspace of $X$. If $U\subset Z$ is open (in $Z$), we define $\mathcal{G}\big|_Z$ as the sheafification of the semi-sheaf $U\mapsto \varinjlim_{V\supset U}\mathcal{G}(V)$ (where $V$ is open in $X$).
>
> If $\varphi:\mathcal{G}\to\iota_*\mathcal{F}$ is a morphism of sheaves (where $\iota:Z\hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion), show that there is a natural induced morphism of sheaves $\varphi':\mathcal{G}\big|_Z\to\mathcal{F}$.

For an open set $U$ of $Z$, I'm trying to define $\varphi'_U:\mathcal{G}\big|_Z(U)\to\mathcal{F}(U)$ from the map $\varphi_U$.

If $s\in\mathcal{G}\big|_Z(U)$, we should find some open $U'$ of $X$ with $U=U'\cap Z$ and some $f\in\mathcal{G}(U')$ in order to define $\varphi'_{U}(s)=\varphi_{U'}(f)$, but I don't know how to do that.

How can I "unrestrict" $s\in\mathcal{G}\big|_Z(U)$ into some $f\in\mathcal{G}(U')$

Comment: Do you know something about the adjunction between the sheaf morphisms $i^{-1}$ and $i_*$?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_image_functor

Comment: If you don't, I strongly encourage you to work this out yourself. It becomes very important in later work.

Comment: @ShubhankarSahai no, I didn't know about it. After reading the section "properties" in the article, I thought it would be a good idea to define $\varphi'$ by the stalk morphisms $(\varphi')_x$. Would you agree?

Comment: Well you already have a morphism $\mathcal{G}|_Z\to \mathcal{F}.$ But the data of a morphism here is an open set $U\subset Z$, a morphism from $\mathcal{G}|_Z(U)\to\mathcal{F}(U) .$ But here $\mathcal{G}|_Z$ is defined via a limit construction, so how do you get a map out of the colimit ?(hint: universal property) Use this fact to find a level wise morphism $\mathcal{G}\to i_*\mathcal{F}$. Workout what sections of $i_*\mathcal{F}$ look like and you should get a pretty explicit map.